# How would I let a user only perform a specific action only a limited number of times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

For instance, I have the following method that allows the user to post something as an advertisement, but I'd like to limit the number of times that this can be performed. I have the following the code:

```
-(void)submitActivity{

  if (numberOfTimesSubmitted > 3){

      //Alert the user that they must pay for additional postings

  }else{

      //submit activity method
   }
}
```

I think that I have the basic overall concept down, but i'm not sure of how to track the number of times the user has performed a specific action. Would I be able to save this in NSUserDefaults? Any ideas?

Comment: Does the user have an account? Should the count be maintained even if the app is deleted and reinstalled?

Comment: Yes, it should be maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is only maintained while the app is installed. When the app is deleted, so are the defaults. If you want to persist the count even if the app is deleted then you should store the count in the keychain (the keychain isn't deleted when the app is deleted).

Arguably you should have a user account so the count can be spread across multiple devices.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Actually we store everything in a server (Username, and password), and authenticate the user. I'll just probably have to come up with an extra field that stores number of submissions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to persist between runs, then yes `NSUserDefaults` is what you're looking for. If you just want to persist in an individual run, then you probably just want an `@property` for the class. Finally, if you're storing sensitive data, you need to use the `Keychain` apis.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To get the data back out:

```
 NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

Alternately, if you want to try a cloud backend, you can use [Parse](https://parse.com/) or [iCloud Key-Value Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html), among others, or your own.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Any suggestions on a keychain wrapper? Thank you, btw.

Comment: I've used SSKeychain in the past https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain and enjoyed it. The API is simple and well thought out.